# Joining Windows 7 Homegroup breaks connections to shares

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, homegroup

I have a Windows 7 Home Premium box that runs as my home server.  I have three accounts on it, my Admin account, a TV account, and a "share" account.  I map a network drive from other PCs and Macs using this share account's credentials.

Recently, I created a Homegroup using the Admin account on the server because, mostly, I was looking into the "built-in" Windows Media Player streaming features to other devices connected to the machine locally and over the Internet.

Unfortunately, I found that after I have these other PCs join the Homegroup, their mapped network drives to the "share" account fails with a "no permissions" error.

I would like some help understanding why the shares break after I join the Homegroup.

Comment: Delete the mappings and remap them while connected to the homegroup server.

Comment: @Moab: I tried that and it didn't fix my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the advanced network settings where you turn on/off file sharing, etc, in the home/work profile setting, there is an option to have home group use your accounts and passwords.  When windows manages it, it uses a common account instead of your account so it breaks the existing permissions.  This seems to work for me.